# Array reduce find the small distance and return id

Tags: arrays, reduce

I use google matrix for calculate the best distance with the multiple address.
I want display the id of a small distance
My array return by the API

```
$com = Array(
        [0] => Array        (
            [id] => 12
            [km] => 833 km

        )

        [1] => Array        (
            [id] => 4
            [km] => 546km

        )

        [1] => Array        (
            [id] => 45
            [km] => 1200km

        )
    )
```

I want display the ID of small distance ( for this exemple the id is "4")

I have tried this :

```
 $min = array_reduce($commercant, 
                        function ($min, $item) {
                           if ($item['km'] < $min['km']) {
                          return $item;
                           }
                           return $min;
                        },
                        array('id' => -1, 'km' => PHP_INT_MAX));
echo $min['id'];
```

This code doesn't work and i don't know why !
if you have an idea....
Thx

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
    usort($com, function($a, $b) {
        return $a['km'] - $b['km'];
    });
   echo !empty($com[0]['id']) ? $com[0]['id'] : "";
```

it will sort your array in desc order of distance, from this sorted array you can pick first element of array.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: `km` key holds string value, be attentive.

Comment: I have tested all solutions, but i have the same problem it's the first result are displayed" ID=12 and 833km "

Answer (score 0):

With ordinary sorting, you can achieve result.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
$x = [
      ['id' => 12, 'km' => '833km'],
      ['id' => 4, 'km' => '546km'],
      ['id' => 45, 'km' => '1200km']
  ];

function cmp_by_kms($arr1, $arr2) {

 $km1 = intval($arr1['km']);
 $km2 = intval($arr2['km']);
 if ($km1 == $km2) { return 0; }
 return ($km1<$km2) ?  -1 : 1;
}
usort($x, "cmp_by_kms");
print_r($x[0]);

#=> Array
 (
     [id] => 4
     [km] => 546km
 )
```